# SQL - How to Group by and then Concatenate joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the made a join between 2 tables but the issue is that I need to see unique
***CustomerId*** and concatenate ***Accreditations*** with comma separated e,i Gold,Silver,Platinum

Here is my SQL script

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 

Customer.CustomerID,
Customer.CustomerName,
Customer_Accreditations.AccreditationNumber


FROM 

Customer INNER JOIN
Customer_Accreditations ON Customer.CustomerID = 
Customer_Accreditations.CustomerID
```

My Result with this script is as follows

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    AccreditationNumber
1272        Bree            Gold        
1272        Bree            Gold        
1272        Bree            Gold       
4071        Anneke          Silver      
4071        Anneke          Silver      
4071        Anneke          Platinum
```

My desired result should be

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    AccreditationNumber
1272        Bree            Gold,Gold,Gold        
4071        Anneke          Silver,Silver,Platinum
```

So far I have only been able to get unique values and concatenate Accreditations
Here is the script:

```
SELECT CustomerID, displayname = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [AccreditationNumber]
               FROM Customer_Accreditations b 
               WHERE b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

FROM [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Customer_Accreditations] a
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

This returns the following results

```
______________________________
|CustomerId  | displayname   |
|____________________________|
|1272        | Gold,Gold,Gold|
______________________________
```

This is great but if only I could join more of Customer tables/

Many thanks!

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. Are you sure it is repeating the names?

Comment: I'm trying to join  tables and then group

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the customers table to get one row per customer.  I think this should be doing what you want:

```
SELECT c.*,
       STUFF( (SELECT ',' + [AccreditationNumber]
               FROM Customer_Accreditations ca
               WHERE ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as displayname
FROM [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Customer] c;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however i'm still not getting my desired result

Comment: @Yosh . . . Well, what is the difference?

Comment: Please note that Customer and Customer_Accreditations  are  different tables, I want to join them then concatenate the Accreditations.. many thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       CustomerName ,
      STUFF(SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + AccreditationNumber
      FROM <Table> i
      WHERE i.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
      FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS AccreditationNumber
FROM <Table> o
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however i'm still not getting my desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, a.CustomerName, displayname = 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [AccreditationNumber]
FROM Customer_Accreditations b 
WHERE b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

FROM [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Customer] a
GROUP BY a.CustomerID, a.CustomerName
```